# Loop with strides in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

If I am having a for loop in c++ with some stride, how can I parallelized it in OpenCL kernel.

For example:

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++4)
   for(int j=0;j<60;j++4)
    {
       a[i]= b[j]+2;
    }
```

In OpenCL, If I want to parallelize the loops, I can think of using **"/"** or **"%"**, but Is there an other solution?
I am thinking something like this:

```
int id1= get_global_id(0);
int id2= get_global_id(1);

if((id1%4==0) && (id2%4==0))
 {
   a[id1] = b[id2]+2;
 }
```

This is just an example, as I want to know, how can work with the stride. Is there any other way?

Comment: what datatype is a and b?  (I assume integer) how many entries are in the two lists?

Comment: If you don't arrange your code to get coalesced reads and writes you will be leaving a lot of performance on the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply id1 and id2 with 4, and set the global size to 100/4 and 60/4 when you launch the kernel.

```
int id1= get_global_id(0)*4;
int id2= get_global_id(1)*4;
a[id1] = b[id2]+2;
```